# Strip values of trailing slashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of URLs in excel cells. The problem is that there are implicit duplicates:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com
```

My idea is to strip the cells values of the "/". And then I'll be able to remove duplicates as usual.

Is there a way to remove trailing slashes if they exist? Preferrable way is to do it without VBA (by means of formulae).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this either in other cells then check for duplicates, or you could integrate this formula directly in your method that is checking for duplicates :

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="/";LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-1);A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### URL Separators

Let's say the data is in column 'A' and starts in the first row put this formula into a cell in the first row e.g. B1, C1 ... :

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(RIGHT(A1,1)<>"/",A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)))
```

`=IF(A1="","",...)` - Checks if there is data in cell 'A1'. If there isn't the result is "".

`... IF(Right(A1,1)<>"/",A1, ...)` - Checks if the last character is not a "/". If it is not, A1 is used.

`... Left(A1,Len(A1)-1)` - The last character is '/' so the value (string) of A1 is shortened by one.

You know how to continue.